# WARNING: tensorflow error -train-single-image

Tags: tensorflow

```
# =========加载fashion_mist数据集===================
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
fashion_mist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist 
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images,test_labels) = fashion_mist.load_data()
#  上方的变量一次对应 训练的图片, 训练的标签,   测试的图片, 测试的标签

# =====================================================
I want to train single image now , but it gives me error
# =======train single image===========

print(test_labels[0])
print(model.predict([[test_images[0]/255]]))
```

This is error

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28), dtype=tf.float32, name='flatten_13_input'), name='flatten_13_input', description="created by layer 'flatten_13_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar error of mine today, you need to make sure the size of model input is same as the size of the input data you are using. You need to reshape your input for that. you can use np.expand_dims() to match the dimensions of both and it should solve the issue.

Comment: thank you , the problem is about dimensions really,  I use `np.expand_dims( )` have resolve it